# Zooming in and out relative to position of the mouse is working, but why does part of the drawn text go out of bounds when zooming in?

Tags: java, swing, awt, zooming

Below is a minimal reproducible code example where you can use mouse wheel to zoom in and out relative to the position of the mouse. The JScrollPane also auto-adjusts its size as you zoom in and out.

```
package testpane;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class TestPane 
{
    public static Drawing d;
    public static double zoomFactor = 1;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Tree Diagram");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new TestPane().makeDiagram());
        f.setSize(1600, 800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public JComponent makeDiagram()
    {
        d = new Drawing();

        MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new TestPaneMouseListener();
        d.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
        d.addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
        d.addMouseWheelListener(mouseAdapter);

        return new JScrollPane(d);
    }
}
```

```
package testpane;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import static testpane.TestPane.d;
import static testpane.TestPane.zoomFactor;

public class TestPaneMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
{ 
    private final Point origin = new Point();

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        Component c = e.getComponent();
        Container p = SwingUtilities.getUnwrappedParent(c);
        if (p instanceof JViewport) 
        {
            JViewport viewport = (JViewport) p;
            Point cp = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(c, e.getPoint(), viewport);
            Point vp = viewport.getViewPosition();
            vp.translate(origin.x - cp.x, origin.y - cp.y);
            ((JComponent) c).scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(vp, viewport.getSize()));
            origin.setLocation(cp);
        }
    }

   @Override
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
   {
       Component c = e.getComponent();
       Container p = SwingUtilities.getUnwrappedParent(c);
       if(p instanceof JViewport) 
       {
           JViewport viewport = (JViewport) p;
           Point cp = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(c, e.getPoint(), viewport);
           origin.setLocation(cp);
       }
   }
   
   @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getWheelRotation()<0)
        {
            zoomFactor*=1.05;
            d.setZoomFactor(1.05);
        }
        
        if(e.getWheelRotation()>0)
        {
            zoomFactor/=1.05;
            d.setZoomFactor(1/1.05);
        }
    }
}
```

```
package testpane;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Drawing extends JPanel
{
    private final AffineTransform zoomTransform = new AffineTransform();
    private final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(1600, 800);
    private double xOffset = 0;
    private double yOffset = 0;
    private double prevZoomFactor = 1;
    
    public Drawing()
    {
        Font currentFont = getFont();
        Font newFont = currentFont.deriveFont(currentFont.getSize() * 15F);
        setFont(newFont);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
    
    public void setZoomFactor(double zoomFactor) 
    {
        zoomTransform.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        AffineTransform scrollTransform = g2d.getTransform();
        
        double xRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - getLocationOnScreen().getX();
        double yRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - getLocationOnScreen().getY();
        
        double zoomDiv = TestPane.zoomFactor / prevZoomFactor;

        xOffset = (zoomDiv) * (xOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * xRel;
        yOffset = (zoomDiv) * (yOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * yRel;

        prevZoomFactor = TestPane.zoomFactor;
        
        scrollTransform.translate(xOffset, yOffset);
        scrollTransform.concatenate(zoomTransform);
        g2d.setTransform(scrollTransform);

        g2d.drawString("Example", 400, 400);
            
        g2d.dispose();
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() 
    {
        Rectangle r = zoomTransform.createTransformedShape(rect).getBounds();
        return new Dimension(r.width, r.height);
    }
}
```

Here is my problem: the zooming works just fine, but when I zoom too close, part of the "Example" written on the JScrollPane goes out of bounds. I believe that the problem comes from the translation I've made inside of the "Drawing" java class in the "paintComponent" method. While this translation does help me zoom in properly, it also causes my text to go out of bounds if I zoom too close. Is there any way for me to fix this?

Comment: Swing is a very dated platform at this point. HTML 5 / CSS 3 / JavaScript is the state of the art these days. So if this is for maintaining legacy software, you've no choice but to grind it out. But if you can, I recommend doing what you are doing in HTML